# the API Usage Last 7 Days report

Tags: reports-api

I have several questions:
1. How do I add a column that shows the date (e.g. )
2. How do I get the API usage for a longer period of time (e.g. month) vs. 7 days

Thanks

Comment: Since these two questions aren't related, it would help the site stay organized if you edited this post to only focus on the API usage issue, and reposted your date question as a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer, you can't

If you click customize after running the report you will see all that is available to you. As for date, you can only do the day of week.

You cannot make it for a longer time..

Comment: @user24477 - please mark this as the correct answer so other can benefit from searching for this question and knowing it has an answer